# jquery on confirm submit correct form in the table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, submit

Hi I have table which lists all registered users. I two options Suspend/Reactive and Delete. I want to show a confirm message before these buttons are submitted so that the user is warned of what will happen if this is processed. So I decieded to use a plugin called [jquery.confirm](http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/jquery.confirm.min.js) which works brilliantly. I have this function setup which I took from the documentation:

```
// SUSPEND USER
$(".suspend-user").confirm({

    text: "Are you sure you want to suspend this user? Login access for this user will be removed.",
    title: "Confirmation required",
    confirm: function(button) {
         $('.suspend-user').closest('form').submit();
    },
    cancel: function(button) {
        // nothing to do
    },
    confirmButton: "Yes I'm sure.",
    cancelButton: "No.",
    post: true,
    confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
    cancelButtonClass: "btn-green"
});
```

So once the user has confirmed this them it will find the closest form and submit it. However it submits the last form that is on the page rather than the closest one, or the one that the button is actually linked too. This is achieved using this code:

```
confirm: function(button) {
         $('.suspend-user').closest('form').submit();
    },
```

Is there a way I can target the correct form? My HTML is as follows or view a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oyo1oye1/1/):

Any help much appreciated

```
<table id="userTable" class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>User Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>user</td>
        <td>user</td>
        <td>useruser</td>
        <td>useruser@gmail.com</td>
        <td> <a href="http://myapp.local/admin/user/1/edit"><span class="icon-edit"></span>Edit</a>

        </td>
        <td>
            <form method="POST" action="http://myapp.local/admin/user/1/delete" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
                <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="cHO3sLY9zjBUfI1J60AShfOeThxQbOVFbDyhpuQo">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger suspend-user"><span class="icon-remove-user"></span>Suspend</button>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form method="POST" action="http://myapp.local/admin/user/1/removeUser" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="delete-user-profile" id="delete-userform">
                <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="cHO3sLY9zjBUfI1J60AShfOeThxQbOVFbDyhpuQo">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete-user dialog-confirm"><span class="icon-trash"></span>Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>P</td>
        <td>b</td>
        <td>user</td>
        <td>useruser+1@gmail.com</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <form method="POST" action="http://myapp.local/admin/user/2/restore" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="cHO3sLY9zjBUfI1J60AShfOeThxQbOVFbDyhpuQo">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green restore-user"><span class="icon-add-user"></span> Re-activate</button>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form method="POST" action="http://myapp.local/admin/user/2/removeUser" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="delete-user-profile" id="delete-userform">
                <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="cHO3sLY9zjBUfI1J60AShfOeThxQbOVFbDyhpuQo">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete-user dialog-confirm"><span class="icon-trash"></span>Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>wegrerhb</td>
        <td>bkhbjhb</td>
        <td>bkjbk</td>
        <td>nrbj@gmail.com</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>
            <form method="POST" action="http://myapp.local/admin/user/28/restore" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="cHO3sLY9zjBUfI1J60AShfOeThxQbOVFbDyhpuQo">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-green restore-user"><span class="icon-add-user"></span> Re-activate</button>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form method="POST" action="http://myapp.local/admin/user/28/removeUser" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="delete-user-profile" id="delete-userform">
                <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="cHO3sLY9zjBUfI1J60AShfOeThxQbOVFbDyhpuQo">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete-user dialog-confirm"><span class="icon-trash"></span>Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>erhreth</td>
        <td>rher</td>
        <td>erheh</td>
        <td>grlnho@gmail.com</td>
        <td> <a href="http://myapp.local/admin/user/29/edit"><span class="icon-edit"></span>Edit</a>

        </td>
        <td>
            <form method="POST" action="http://myapp.local/admin/user/29/delete" accept-charset="UTF-8">
                <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
                <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="cHO3sLY9zjBUfI1J60AShfOeThxQbOVFbDyhpuQo">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger suspend-user"><span class="icon-remove-user"></span>Suspend</button>
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form method="POST" action="http://myapp.local/admin/user/29/removeUser" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="delete-user-profile" id="delete-userform">
                <input name="_method" type="hidden" value="DELETE">
                <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="cHO3sLY9zjBUfI1J60AShfOeThxQbOVFbDyhpuQo">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger delete-user dialog-confirm"><span class="icon-trash"></span>Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$('.suspend-user')` is finding all of the forms and submitting them all.

You need to submit the form you are on. It looks like the plug-in passes the button that was clicked so:

```
confirm: function(button) {
     $(button).closest('form').submit();
},
```

Comment: @espascarello this works! thanks. I thought my approach would be looking at the last form as thats what testing showed but thanks for that it works now

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
$(button).parents('form:first').submit();
```

This takes the first parent with a from tag it can find. As all of your suspend-user buttons are inside the form to submit it should work.

When you write

```
$('.suspend-user').closest('form').submit();
```

how should it know which of the suspend-user classes you mean. so it takes the last it can find. and takes the closest form to submit.

Comment: good point you've made. I did think this too when I was doing $(this) on the `closest` function but this didn't work. I've tried your method but this doesn't work either. Nothing happens on the page and I don't get an error. Any other suggestions?

Comment: actually try what epascarello wrote, $(button).closest ... or before "confirm: ..." save $(this) in a variable like var clickedButton = $(this); And in the confirm part use it like clickedButton.closest('form').submit()

Answer (score 0):

You can also use jQuery Confirm plugin post method:-

```
$(".confirm").confirm({
    text: "Are you sure you want to delete that comment?",
    title: "Confirmation required",
    confirm: function(button) {
        delete();
    },
    cancel: function(button) {
        // nothing to do
    },
    confirmButton: "Yes I am",
    cancelButton: "No",
    post: true,
    confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
    cancelButtonClass: "btn-default"
});
```

You can also go through documentation at http://myclabs.github.io/jquery.confirm/

And if you don't want to use this you can also tru using jQuery code to submit this for:-

```
jQuery(this).parent('form:first').submit();
```